# share files from windows 10 hotmail account to windows 7 local account without password

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Windows 7 with local account no password.
Windows 10 with hotmail account (and of course with a password)
Win7 machine called mylaptop in workgroup OURGROUP
win10  machine called mypc in workgroup OURGROUP
Both with Home-group created (same password).

Don't see files from one to the other...
Wish to share between the two, from one to the other.
What do I need to do.

This is NOT windows 8. It is Windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share any folder without password in Windows 8/10 in a home network if a Microsoft account is involved?](http://superuser.com/questions/827986/how-to-share-any-folder-without-password-in-windows-8-10-in-a-home-network-if-a)

Comment: I found an answer outside Superuser. Has to do with registry in windows 10. 

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-10-network-share-access.html

Doesn't answer the same question vise versa, and of course does not explain why cannot access from 10 (with pw) to 7 (without)

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: Yesterday, when I reopened the thread I could not answer my own question yet. Today, when I can, I don't wish to, because it turns out that I still cannot access the files either way. So the question is left open.

Comment: Also, the listed "duplicate" of this question in his accepted "answer" just brings up a similar problem to this one, while not answering the question(s) at all, only reiterating the similar but different question.

Comment: bump - question still relevant