# Windows Access Network Computer Files Shows No Files For User

Tags: networking, windows-10

So I enabled Turn on Network discovery and Turned on file and printer sharing on a friends laptop I was trying to work on. Having done something like this before, I didn't think I'd have a hiccup in doing it again but I can't exactly remember what I did to fix it.

I went to the network places and doubled clicked on his computer. It brought up the box for insert username. I put in

```
\\The-Computer\TheUser
```

which it accepted and then asked for the password. He currently has no password set on his computer so I just hit enter (which I'm pretty sure is where I messed up). It opened up to a blank folder.

After playing with

```
cmd> net use
```

for a bit and deleting the network location attempting to log out of the computer and try to log back in, so I could set a password on the remote computer and then give it a password, it won't log out.

So I guess my question is, how do you log out of a network computer you've already "logged into"... and is there a default password that is set for network connections if there is no password set?

Update:

Tried playing some more with net ...

```
net view
```

returns the computer as still being there

```
net computer \\The-Computer /DEL
```

this returns an error:

```
This command can be used only on a Windows Domain Controller.
```

I don't understand why windows doesn't just include a "Disconnect from this computer" option in the network settings...

Comment: He has to specifically share the folder with you, a user, on another pc.

Comment: By default, file sharing without a password is disabled. See this answer to a similar question which shows how to enable it.http://superuser.com/a/1005213/250153

Comment: I've disabled the password sharing, and the files still don't appear. I finally just got fed up with it and took the extra steps to move things around Public but It still bugs me