# Howto share a drive on the local network in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

At home, I have a desktop pc running Windows 10.
Previously, I used windows homegroup functionality to share some directories over the network with other computers.

Now that windows has removed the homegroup functionality, I am looking for a way to share a directory or a even a drive with the network.

What is my setup?

- Windows 10 pc will function as the server, always latest update
- Connected to LAN with a gigabit connection.
- All machines on the LAN are also running windows 10.

What do I want to do

- Share the drive on the network
- Make sure other pc's can read and write from and to the shared drive

What have I already looked up?

- Sharing in windows 10 (advanced sharing) --> I don't manage to get this working
- I looked up how to share the network on the drive with a third party software, but without any success.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092694/windows-10-changes-to-file-sharing-over-a-network

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this explains howto share a directory of a file with specific users, but what I would like to do is share a complete disk with the LAN. So, if a new user joins the network, he or she should be able to connect to the drive without changing the server setup.

Comment: https://pureinfotech.com/setup-network-file-sharing-windows-10/

Comment: Just allow anonymous/everyone access to the share. If you're using Windows 10 you might have to enable anonymous/everyone access to shares. See also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/827986/how-to-share-any-folder-without-password-in-windows-8-10-in-a-home-network-if-a) question.

Comment: "Sharing in windows 10 (advanced sharing) --> I don't manage to get this working" Did you enable file and printer sharing first? What error are you getting? Otherwise, Seth's comment would be relevant since I've only shared folders using local accounts.

Comment: I did not enable this first. The thing I tried was using the advanced sharing option, and giving access to everyone. When I tried to connect from another pc, the pc was listed in the network tab. Clicking the pc asked for credentials, which refused to let me in from that other pc.

But if I read the description correctly, I should add the name I give the share on the other pc