# Windows 10 local network sharing issues

Tags: windows-10, networking, file-sharing

I have a Windows 10 (Home) laptop and a Windows 10 (Pro) PC that I'd like to connect via local area network (wifi only) so I can pass files from one to the other.

I have followed [this youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gprPi_8aUk&ab_channel=Britec09) which seems fairly straight forward and comprehensive.

The issue I am having is that I can successfully access my PC from my laptop, but it seems I cannot do the reverse.

For context, I am using VNC Server/Viewer when interacting with my PC from my Laptop, but I don't think this should have any bearing over the issue.

**Settings > Network & Internet > Properties**

| Laptop | PC |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

**Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Centre > Change advanced sharing settings**

| Laptop | PC |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

I believe I followed all the process successfully, I can see both my laptop and my pc within the network window

| Laptop | PC |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

however when attempting to access the laptop from the pc I get the dialogue box:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Do both computers have the same type of user account, meaning both are local or both are Microsoft accounts?

Comment: From the Desktop  NET USE T: \\nameoflaptop\folder   .   What numerical error number do you get?   Also try NET USE with IP address.

Comment: @harrymc As far as I'm aware they do... Not sure how I should check that. They're both the standard accounts that were established when installing Windows etc. The laptop has my Microsoft account signed in whereas the PC does not.

Comment: @John what a strange occurrance... I navigated on my PC to `\\MY-LAPTOP\Users\me` and I could get through! However, going back to the Network tab and trying to access `MY-LAPTOP` again, I get the same error.... There is no numerical error code as far as I can see, it's literally just the error box shown in the screenshot.

Comment: On the laptop make a user that is the user name on the Desktop.    Restart both computers and try connecting again.  NET USE T:  .....   from a command prompt should produce an error number and then the error. Common message.

Comment: @John seems like it's playing up and not letting me add a new user at the moment. When you say `NET USE T: \\nameoflaptop\folder`, Is the `T:` something I should replace or keep it the same?

Comment: T: is just a drive letter - use any letter good for you on your system.  Also there must be some error in your laptop OS if you cannot add a user

Comment: @John I performed the command `NET USE T: \\My-Laptop\Users\Me` on the PC and got the message, `The command completed successfully`... Looking at `this pc` there's no `T` drive in there...

Comment: There appears to be an error in your OS if NET USE does not result in a drive letter and if you cannot add a user.

Comment: Maybe so. Maybe it just needs a good restart. Anyhow... I think I've managed to get what I want out of this... A shared folder that I can add files to from either end and access at the other.

Comment: @physicsboy: You might have run into [this problem](https://superuser.com/a/858666/8672) of non-matching accounts.